# Fail to run Jenkins locally on Docker Container using Agent with Docker installed

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I want to run jenkins locally with docker and run a pipeline that pulls and build docker containers. I have a Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
USER root
RUN apt update && curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com | sh
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins
USER jenkins
```

I build it with: `docker build . -t ltscustomjenkins`
I run it with `docker run -dit --restart=always -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ltscustomjenkins`

I then log register jenkins on localhost and install recommended updates.
I build another Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/agent
USER root
RUN apt update && curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com | sh
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins
USER jenkins
```

and run it as  `docker build . -t jenkinsagent`

I install the command agent launcher plugin. I add a new node called dockeragent. As remote root directory I use: /home/jenkins/agent, and launch method: Launch agent via execution of command on the controller. My launch command is
 `docker run -i --rm --name agent -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --init jenkinsagent java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/agent.jar`

When I want to launch the agent I get the error:

```
$ docker run -i --rm --name agent -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --init jenkinsagent java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/agent.jar
docker: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Head "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
ERROR: Unable to launch the agent for dockeragent
java.io.EOFException: unexpected stream termination
    at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.negotiate(ChannelBuilder.java:459)
    at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.build(ChannelBuilder.java:404)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:440)
    at hudson.slaves.CommandLauncher.launch(CommandLauncher.java:170)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.lambda$_connect$0(SlaveComputer.java:297)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
ERROR: Process terminated with exit code 126
```

As far as I researched using 'RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins' in my dockerfiles should be enough but I still get this error. Any ideas are apprecoated. Thanks!

Comment: With which user you are building your docker images?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your docker group from the host has a different group ID than the docker group created inside the Jenkins container.

You could try:

- edit the Dockerfile adding a command to remove the docker group created by the docker install script;
- create a new docker group with the same ID from your host. Use the command "cat /etc/group" in a terminal from your host to see which ID has the docker group.